# Relative compactification without resolutions of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, characteristic-p, resolution-of-singularities

Let $Y$ be a smooth proper variety over a field $k$, let $X$ be a smooth variety over $k$, $U\hookrightarrow X$ the complement of a strict normal crossing divisor and $\phi\colon U\to Y$ a map. By Nagata's theorem, there exists a proper binational map $X'\to X$ that is an isomorphism on $U$ such that $\phi$ extends to $X'\to Y$.

In characteristic zero, by Hironaka's theorem we can choose $X'\to X$ to be a sequence of blow-ups in smooth centers. Is anything known in this direction in positive characteristics, without modifying $U$ with alterations? Is the problem easier if the target $Y$ is a curve or a surface?

Comment: If $Y$ is a curve of genus $\geq 1$, $\phi$ extends to a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$...

Comment: Really? I have never seen a result like this, can you explain it to me?

Comment: This is usually stated with $Y$ an abelian variety. Then this implies the result for any subvariety of  an abelian variety, for instance a curve of genus $\geq 1$.

Comment: It also extends to N'eron models of Abelian varieties (it is roughly the defining property of a N'eron model).  Sometimes it is called "Weil extension."

Comment: Oh I see, yes I know the result on abelian varieties but I did not think about using it for the result, as abelian varieties are a bit too special. Thank you both very much!

Comment: There is almost certainly no general argument that does not use Hironaka.  Let $Z$ be an arbitrary (singular) projective variety with an embedding in $X=\mathbb{P}^n$.  Let $X'$ be the blowing up of $X$ along $Z$, and let $X'\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^r$ be a closed immersion.  For this rational transformation, $X\dashrightarrow Y$, a sequence of blowups with smooth centers that regularizes the transformation also implies a resolution of singularities of $Z$.

Comment: Ok I see, this was definitely too optimistic. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: There is an alternative argument for projective varieties $Y$ for which every morphism $\mathbf P^1\to Y$ is constant (this includes subvarieties of abelian varieties). Indeed, consider the closure $\bar\Gamma$ of the graph $\Gamma_\phi\subseteq X\times Y$, which maps birationally onto $X$ via the first projection $p\colon\bar\Gamma\to X$. When $X$ is smooth, such a map has linearly connected fibres by a result of Murre, which (by assumption on $Y$) are contracted by the second projection $q\colon\bar\Gamma\to Y$. Then $q$ factors through $p$, i.e. $\phi$ is everywhere defined.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice clarification :)